# Strongly-typed Rest client implementation with Typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

I have this interface:

```
export interface WorkoutLibrary {
"/Workout": {
    get: (
        input?: GetWorkoutListOptions
    ) => Promise<GetWorkoutList200Response | ErrorResponse>;
    post: (
        input: CreateWorkoutOptions
    ) => Promise<CreateWorkout201Response | ErrorResponse>;
    put: (
        input: UpdateWorkoutOptions
    ) => Promise<UpdateWorkout200Response | ErrorResponse>;
};
"/workout/{workoutId}": {
    get: (
        input?: GetWorkout200Response
    ) => Promise<GetWorkout200Response | ErrorResponse>;
    delete: (
        input?: DeleteWorkoutOptions
    ) => Promise<DeleteWorkout200Response | ErrorResponse>;
}
```

}

The problem is I do not know how to implement this to make actual calls to my API.
Can someone provide an example on how to actually implement this in a class to use, let's say Axios, to make the API calls?

Probably I am missing some key Typescript concepts here, but I am kind of new to it.
If someone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you just asking how to to implement this interface? Something like this? https://tsplay.dev/WKKQgW If so I can write that up as an answer. If not, then please [edit] your question and add more detail about what it is you want here.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. It might seem like a very simple question, but I am very new to Typescript and I am missing some important key concepts still. Thanks a lot for the answer, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Check out Zodios / TS-Rest , theese two libs do basically this I guess (Zodios uses Axios/Express, TS-Rest uses whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement this type, you just make an object that matches those property and function types:

For simplicity, let's focus on one:

```
export interface WorkoutLibrary {
  "/Workout": {
    get: (input?: GetWorkoutListOptions) =>
      Promise<GetWorkoutList200Response | ErrorResponse>;
  }
}
```

Now your question is missing some types, so let's say those are lie this:

```
type ErrorResponse = { error: string }

type GetWorkoutListOptions = { type: 'arms' | 'legs' | 'core' }
type GetWorkoutList200Response = { name: string }[]
```

Now you can make an implementation like this:

```
const workoutLibrary: WorkoutLibrary = {
  '/Workout': {
    get: async (input) => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `http://example.com/Workout?type=${input?.type ?? 'all'}`
        )

        const json = await response.json()
        return json
      } catch (error) {
        return { error }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This creates an object that matches the `WorkoutLibrary` type and its functions. It uses [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to fetch a url, and the input is used in that URL. If an error occurred, it returns something in the shape of `ErrorReponse`.

And then you can call this function like so:

```
await workoutLibrary['/Workout'].get({ type: 'core' })
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogTnA9nAShAzmRA7d0C8UA3lBAsgFxTrBwCW2A5lAL4BQbokUA4hMAHVkAa0QBXYABk6NAPJhgdHOiiESXCFQDkAQzgBbdFqgAfKFoA2ERkdPmAxsgjGzuixePsNvfkLiiJaRoAJgAGULRMZQJiKGwdfU1qWgZmFgBtAF0OCAAPLDhgKAZgMgAzHXtoPwCpOgAjOD0QYjYoKAAiAHoa8WAOqiI29qhGfioACgYwCQB+Kj5BET6g4HlFZQBKVQA+YZGoAAUkfRkIAB5F3sCZYDCIjCxcaDN4JFRH6J2AbmH2djYjlwRQA7ssbo1mlRrnVIXAWmphloeuDgFpBvtRuMoDp0CBsPYoFNsDNgNt8DtWgd2rQWkNqSMgTQoHBPs9VDiQTo6EUyvx7AALCaYhkAAwFwGAYAoXS6eQSYCsADpHPoUf4+rMNPgACREaZzJXeWazcw6dxaFiikUjTYcBntJlFABW6BwHJ0XJ5LLZeCVrpwEztDp9wDEcGwUAD2BtLCg9h0wEFRLI7229IdrLDEdiqeQrFjmPY7X+HDYnu5oNR0jhIHSyJhWkySrGwAm6nASV0BlsLE2QA)

---

Note, there are many ways to achieve this, and may libraries you could use. This code should merely be thought of as an example and a starting point.